# FULLPAGE: when reaching the last slide, do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using Fullpage on my portfolio page.
All I want to achieve is that when you reach the last slide, something happens.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any precious help.

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
controlArrowColor: "#000",
onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {
    if (index === $('.fp-section.active .fp-slide').length) {
        window.location.href = "http://google.com"
    }
}
});
```

```css
.section {
    text-align:center;
    font:10vw/1.2em -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,sans-serif;
    background:#fff;
    letter-spacing:.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgithub.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide">ONE</div>
        <div class="slide">TWO</div>
        <div class="slide">THREE</div>
        <div class="slide">REDIRECT</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the indexes 1-based or 0-based

Comment: Not familiar with Fullscreen, but from a quick look at your code: The `index` might start at 0, try `.length-1`

Comment: Index starting from 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of accessing `index`, you should be accessing the `nextSlideIndex`. [As per the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onslideleave-anchorlink-index-slideindex-direction-nextslideindex):

- `index` refers to the **index of the section**. Starting from 1.
- `slideIndex` refers to the **index of the slide**. Starting from 0.
- `nextSlideIndex` refers to the **index of the destination slide**. Starting from 0. (And this is the one you want to check against)

  > Note: `index` will always be `1` because you only have a single section on the page :)

Since `nextSlideIndex` is a zero-based index, you should compare it to one minus the total length of the slides to know if you have reached the final slide.

```
if (nextSlideIndex === $('.fp-section.active .fp-slide').length - 1) {
    // Final slide reached
    console.log('Final slide reached');
}
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  controlArrowColor: "#000",
  onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {
    if (nextSlideIndex === $('.fp-section.active .fp-slide').length - 1) {
      // Final slide reached
      console.log('Final slide reached');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.section {
  text-align: center;
  font: 10vw/1.2em -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgithub.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="slide">ONE</div>
    <div class="slide">TWO</div>
    <div class="slide">THREE</div>
    <div class="slide">REDIRECT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** If you want to perform the action **after** the slides have finished transitioning, I recommend listening to the [`afterSlideLoad` callback](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex):

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  controlArrowColor: "#000",
  afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
    if (slideIndex === $('.fp-section.active .fp-slide').length - 1) {
      // Final slide reached
      console.log('Final slide reached');
    }
  }
});
```

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  controlArrowColor: "#000",
  afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
    if (slideIndex === $('.fp-section.active .fp-slide').length - 1) {
      // Final slide reached
      console.log('Final slide reached');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.section {
  text-align: center;
  font: 10vw/1.2em -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgithub.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="slide">ONE</div>
    <div class="slide">TWO</div>
    <div class="slide">THREE</div>
    <div class="slide">REDIRECT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Federico Glad it helped. I have updated my answer to fix some typos, and also added an additional section in the end, if you want to perform the check **after** the slide has transitioned

Comment: the afterSlideLoad is what I was actually looking for. Thanks so so much.